# Hash Table: Which is the right linear-probing array?

Tags: arrays, hash, hashtable

I am studying data structures right now and in specific Hash Tables. I came across the follow question:

```
Imagine that we have placed the following keys 
in an initial empty hash table with a length of 7
with linear probing, using the following table of hash-values:

key:    A B C D E F G
hash:   3 1 4 1 5 2 5

Which of the following arrays could be the linear-probing array?

1.
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
G B D F A C E

2.
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
B G D F A C E

3.
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
E G F A B C D
```

When I create the linear-probing array I get this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
G B D A C E F
```

Could somebody please tell me why I am wrong and whats the right answer?

Comment: The question doesn't specify the order of the insertion of the keys. Notice how if you insert B-D-F-A-C-E-G, you'd get table 1 as the result.

Comment: In that case it should be on a puzzle place, not a computer course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how the question doesn't specify the order in which the keys are inserted, so your answer is only correct assuming that the keys are actually inserted in the order A-B-C-D-E-F-G, but since the question doesn't explicitly state the order, you need to dig deeper.

What you do know, however, is that one of those keys will be inserted first and it will go to its designated slot as shown in the Key-to-Hash diagram, since the hash table is initially empty. This immediately discards option choice 2 because none of the keys are in their designated array entry, leaving you with choice 1 and 3.

For table 1, `B` is in slot 1, which corresponds to its hash value and for table 3, keys `F` and `A` are in their initial hash-value spots.

It's simple to prove that no sequence of key inserts on table 3 after inserting `F` and `A` will yield table 3 as a result. And its likewise easy to prove that the sequence of key inserts `B-D-F-A-C-E-G` will result in table 1.

Although this is a question based on hash tables, I honestly don't consider it a good way to assess your knowledge on linear probing, this is more of a puzzle, as @gnasher729 mentioned.

Comment: Wow thank you sooo much! And yeah, its was question on my previous data structures exam... I think the way the question is asked is wrong.. It should be "In what order were the items added to the array"  or something like that. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3302735, Glad I could help! If this solved your problem, I'd appreciate if you [could mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Haha, sorry. I'm still a SO newbie. Done!